# How to dynamically assign lambda<expression<delegate>> to expression<delegate>

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I am trying to make dynamic expression and assign lambda to it. As a result, I got exception: 
System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'Test.ItsTrue' cannot be used for assignment to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[Test.ItsTrue]'

What is wrong?

```
public delegate bool ItsTrue();

public class Sample
{
    public Expression<ItsTrue> ItsTrue { get; set; }
}

[TestClass]
public class MyTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestPropertySetWithExpressionOfDelegate()
    {
        Expression<ItsTrue> itsTrue = () => true;

        // this works at compile time
        new Sample().ItsTrue = itsTrue;

        // this does not work ad runtime
        var new_ = Expression.New(typeof (Sample));

        var result = Expression.Assign(
            Expression.Property(new_, typeof (Sample).GetProperties()[0]), 
            itsTrue);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `Expression.Assign` is the *expression* representing the value to assign. So currently you're effectively trying to assign an `ItsTrue` to the property. You need to wrap it so that it's an expression returning the value `itsTrue`... either via `Expression.Quote` or `Expression.Constant`. For example:

```
var result = Expression.Assign(
    Expression.Property(new_, typeof (Sample).GetProperties()[0]), 
    Expression.Constant(itsTrue, typeof(Expression<ItsTrue>)));
```

Alternatively, you *might* want `Expression.Quote` - it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Jon, Expression.Quote is exactly what I expect to be there.